# How to deobfuscate opy python

Tags: python, obfuscation

I'm trying to deobfuscate a code that got obfuscated [using opy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Opy) :

```
# coding: UTF-8
import sys
l1l1ll11lll1l_opy_ = sys.version_info [0] == 2
l11l11lll1_opy_ = 2048
l111l1llllll_opy_ = 7
def l1l1l11ll11ll_opy_ (l1111111lllll_opy_):
    global l1l11111ll1l1_opy_
    l11ll1ll1l_opy_ = ord (l1111111lllll_opy_ [-1])
    l1lll1l1llll_opy_ = l1111111lllll_opy_ [:-1]
    l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_ = l11ll1ll1l_opy_ % len (l1lll1l1llll_opy_)
    l1l1l111ll1_opy_ = l1lll1l1llll_opy_ [:l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_] + l1lll1l1llll_opy_ [l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_:]
    if l1l1ll11lll1l_opy_:
        l11l11111ll1_opy_ = l1ll1ll111ll_opy_ () .join ([l111l1111l_opy_ (ord (char) - l11l11lll1_opy_ - (l1lll1_opy_ + l11ll1ll1l_opy_) % l111l1llllll_opy_) for l1lll1_opy_, char in enumerate (l1l1l111ll1_opy_)])
    else:
        l11l11111ll1_opy_ = str () .join ([chr (ord (char) - l11l11lll1_opy_ - (l1lll1_opy_ + l11ll1ll1l_opy_) % l111l1llllll_opy_) for l1lll1_opy_, char in enumerate (l1l1l111ll1_opy_)])
    return eval (l11l11111ll1_opy_)
```

[obf.py](https://pastebin.com/DhbwQDqs).
I genuinely have no idea where to start.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just keep track of all the identifiers and attempt to rename them to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step could be to look for variables with a regex (all the variable names begin with some `l` and `1`s).

Once you have this `set` of variable names, you could rename to more recognizable names (e.g. `'a'..'z'`) with a `dict`.

Looking at the methods and operators used on those variables, you could recognize which one are supposed to be strings, ints or lists.

```
text = """# coding: UTF-8
import sys
l1l1ll11lll1l_opy_ = sys.version_info [0] == 2
l11l11lll1_opy_ = 2048
l111l1llllll_opy_ = 7
def l1l1l11ll11ll_opy_ (l1111111lllll_opy_):
    global l1l11111ll1l1_opy_
    l11ll1ll1l_opy_ = ord (l1111111lllll_opy_ [-1])
    l1lll1l1llll_opy_ = l1111111lllll_opy_ [:-1]
    l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_ = l11ll1ll1l_opy_ % len (l1lll1l1llll_opy_)
    l1l1l111ll1_opy_ = l1lll1l1llll_opy_ [:l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_] + l1lll1l1llll_opy_ [l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_:]
    if l1l1ll11lll1l_opy_:
        l11l11111ll1_opy_ = l1ll1ll111ll_opy_ () .join ([l111l1111l_opy_ (ord (char) - l11l11lll1_opy_ - (l1lll1_opy_ + l11ll1ll1l_opy_) % l111l1llllll_opy_) for l1lll1_opy_, char in enumerate (l1l1l111ll1_opy_)])
    else:
        l11l11111ll1_opy_ = str () .join ([chr (ord (char) - l11l11lll1_opy_ - (l1lll1_opy_ + l11ll1ll1l_opy_) % l111l1llllll_opy_) for l1lll1_opy_, char in enumerate (l1l1l111ll1_opy_)])
    return eval (l11l11111ll1_opy_)"""


pattern = re.compile(r'\b[l1]{3,}\w+\b')
original_names = set(re.findall(pattern, text))
possible_names = 'abcdefghijklmno'
variable_conversion = dict(zip(original_names, possible_names))
# {'l1ll1ll111ll_opy_': 'a', 'l111l1111l_opy_': 'b', 'l1l1ll11lll1l_opy_': 'c', 'l1111111lllll_opy_': 'm', 'l1l1l111ll1_opy_': 'd', 'l1lll1l1llll_opy_': 'g', 'l11l11lll1_opy_': 'l', 'l1l1l11ll11ll_opy_': 'f', 'l111l1llllll_opy_': 'n', 'l11ll1ll1l_opy_': 'j', 'l1l11111ll1l1_opy_': 'h', 'l1lll1l1ll1111_opy_': 'k', 'l11l11111ll1_opy_': 'e', 'l1lll1_opy_': 'i'}

def replace_by_clearer_name(matchobj):
    original_name = matchobj.group(0)
    return variable_conversion[original_name]

print re.sub(pattern, replace_by_clearer_name, text)
```

It outputs:

```
# coding: UTF-8
import sys
c = sys.version_info [0] == 2
l = 2048
n = 7
def f (m):
    global h
    j = ord (m [-1])
    g = m [:-1]
    k = j % len (g)
    d = g [:k] + g [k:]
    if c:
        e = a () .join ([b (ord (char) - l - (i + j) % n) for i, char in enumerate (d)])
    else:
        e = str () .join ([chr (ord (char) - l - (i + j) % n) for i, char in enumerate (d)])
    return eval (e)
```

Now that looks much more manageable, right?